# Click action links (delete, view, edit) in a row using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I would like to ask for some help on how to click the action links I have in a table.

The HTML page looks like below.

```
Lebron James     | EDIT | VIEW | DELETE
Chris Paul       | EDIT | VIEW | DELETE
Carmelo Anthony  | EDIT | VIEW | DELETE
```

The html format looks like below.

```
<tr>
     <td>Lebron James</td>
     <td>
          <a href="/Player/Edit/282">Edit</a>
          <a href="/Player/View/282">View</a>
          <a href="/Player/Delete/282">Delete</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried the following syntax below.

1. `webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(), 'Chris Paul')]"` + `webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("//td/a[contains(href=\"/Player/Delete/)]")))).Click();`
2. `webDriver.FindElement(ByXPath("//td[contains(text(), 'Carmelo Anthony')]//td/a(href="/Player/Delete")")).Click();`

Syntax above probably not accurate for what I've tried a while ago but they look similar to that. I was able to locate the name in the row but I was not able to click the action links parallel to the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using `xpath` with [`following-sibling` axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) as below :-

- to click on `Edit` link :-

  ```
  webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[text() = 'Lebron James']/following-sibling::td/a[text() = 'Edit']")).click();
  ```
- to click on `View` link :-

  ```
  webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[text() = 'Lebron James']/following-sibling::td/a[text() = 'View']")).click();
  ```
- to click on `Delete` link :-

  ```
  webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[text() = 'Lebron James']/following-sibling::td/a[text() = 'Delete']")).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but the program says it is a invalid xpath expression. Do you think we still need the keyword contains?

Comment: Here's the error on stacktrace
<blockquote>Test method Tests.SeleniumTest.DeleteDept threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//td[text() = 'Lebron James']/following-sibling::td/a[text() = 'Delete']"}
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

Im using the syntax below:
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[text() = 'Lebron James']/following-sibling::td/a[text() = 'Delete']")).Click();

Comment: Its now working. I just made some changes on your syntax. Thank you very much. | webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(),'Lebron James')]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(text(),'Delete')]")).Click(); |

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting this selector would be:

`//td[text()='Lebron James']/..//a[contains(@href, 'Edit')]`

Or if you prefer text:

`//td[text()='Lebron James']/..//a[text()='Edit']`

In this way you will search for `td` containing the text you need, navigate to parent, being `tr` and find in this the link that contains the text that you need in `href` value or in text.

If you don't care about the name you can use a css like:
a[href*='Edit']